# Cosmos DB: How to set the value of partition key to id when create a document?

Tags: azure, azure-cosmosdb

I want to create a container like this:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/how-to-model-partition-example#posts-container

```
{
    "id": "<post-id>",
    "type": "post",
    "postId": "<post-id>",
    "userId": "<post-author-id>",
    "title": "<post-title>",
    "content": "<post-content>",
    "creationDate": "<post-creation-date>"
}
...
```

`postId` is the partition key of this container and I have to set its value equal to `id`.

How to do this?

1. I create a post.
2. Cosmos DB set its `id`
3. I set its `postId` equal to `id` <- How?

Comment: Have you considered setting the id values yourself?

Comment: What are you using .net? Java?

Comment: @juunas I don't know how to create unique id myself. If possible, I want to use auto-increment id.

Comment: @VovaBilyachat JavaScript.

Comment: Dont use autoincrement

Comment: @PONPON for javascript https://www.npmjs.com/package/uuid this is probably way to go

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think from that page idea is that you will have same entity so you can query your cosmos easier.

So in terms how do you set id its simple you will need to set it yourself

```
document.Id = "post-id";
document.PostId = "post-id";
```

On the other hand if you are using lets say .net what you can do

```
public class Document
    {
        
        public string Id { get; set; }
        public string Type { get; set; }
        public string PostId { get; set; }

        public static Document CreatePost(string postId)
        {
            return new Document()
            {
                Id = postId,
                PostId = postId,
                Type = "post"
            };
        }

        public static Document CreateComment(string postId, string commentId)
        {
            return new Document()
            {
                Id = commentId,
                PostId = postId,
                Type = "comment"
            };
        }
    }
```

So then in your code you will do

```
var post = Document.CreatePost(Guid.NewGuid().ToString())
```

Comment: @PONPON in c# its Guid.NewGuid()